# Are triangles allowed in retopology of the model for games?

Tags: retopology

I want use this model in Unreal Engine.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First , to work in quads in your modeler has nothing to do with the game engine. Game engines is for the final result. They usually work with Tris. But your modeler is for making the graphics. And here you can also use Quads and Ngons when required.

A quad topology is much better to judge and to work at. Just half as much edges in the way. And you see how the loops are going. Your modeling software also relies at a quad topology for quite a few tools. Like everything that works with loops. A cut loop will not work as expected at a tri topology. The tris will lead the loop in wrong directions. Or stuff like Subdivision Surface. Tris will not work well here neither. It will produce so called poles. Same goes for rigging and animation. Here you are again much better suited with quads. Because they keep the topology and edge- and faceloops intact.

When done and when export it to the game engine it is better to triangulate the mesh before we do so. Because at import the game engine may triangulate quads or Ngons of the mesh in another way than our modeler. Which can lead to unexpected results. Wrong deformations, or convex faces where it was concave before.